# Challenge Activity - C++ Unit Testing of a Class

Tags: c++, unit-testing

> Write a unit test for addInventory(), which has an error. Call
>   redSweater.addInventory() with parameter sweaterShipment. Print the
>   shown error if the subsequent quantity is incorrect. Sample output for
>   failed unit test given initial quantity is 10 and sweaterShipment is
>   50:
>
> ```
> Beginning tests.
>    UNIT TEST FAILED: addInventory()
> Tests complete.
> ```
>
> Note: UNIT TEST FAILED is preceded by 3 spaces.

Yes, this is an assignment for a C++ programming class. I have tried to add various member objects from the below class to no avail, unfortunately I am stuck and would like some hints, not answers, on how to learn and proceed. Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class InventoryTag {
public:
   InventoryTag();
   int getQuantityRemaining() const;
   void addInventory(int numItems);

private:
   int quantityRemaining;
};

InventoryTag::InventoryTag() {
   quantityRemaining = 0;
}

int InventoryTag::getQuantityRemaining() const {
   return quantityRemaining;
}

void InventoryTag::addInventory(int numItems) {
   if (numItems > 10) {
      quantityRemaining = quantityRemaining + numItems;
   }
}

int main() {
   InventoryTag redSweater;
   int sweaterShipment;
   int sweaterInventoryBefore;

   sweaterInventoryBefore = redSweater.getQuantityRemaining();
   cin >> sweaterShipment;

   cout << "Beginning tests." << endl;

   // FIXME add unit test for addInventory

   /* Your solution goes here  */
      redSweater.addInventory(sweaterShipment);
   if (redSweater.addInventory(sweaterShipment) != 50){
      cout << "   UNIT TEST FAILED: addInventory()\n";
   }

   cout << "Tests complete." << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

EDIT: SOLVED, solution below

```
   // FIXME add unit test for addInventory

   /* Your solution goes here  */
   redSweater.addInventory(sweaterShipment);
   if (redSweater.getQuantityRemaining() != sweaterShipment){
      cout << "   UNIT TEST FAILED: addInventory()\n";
   }
```

Comment: Technical note: Stack Overflow doesn't deal with hints all that well. The preference is for concrete answers. What it looks like you are tripping over here is `addInventory` doesn't return anything so there is nothing for you to test. However (here's the hint) `addInventory`'s job is to modify `quantityRemaining`, so what you really want to do is confirm that `quantityRemaining` has the correct value after `addInventory` is done. How you can read the value of `quantityRemaining`, a `private` member in `main`, I'll leave up to you.

Comment: thanks for the help, figured it out after your explanation. how do i mark as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest of unit tests:

```
InventoryTag tag;
bool success = true;
TEST(tag.getQuantityRemaining() == 0, "initial quantity is zero");
tag.addInventory(1);
TEST(tag.getQuantityRemaining() == 1, "expected inventory is now 1");
```

Where TEST is some macro defined as follows:

```
#define TEST(expression, msg) {if (!(expression)) {success = false; cout << "TEST_FAILED: " << msg << endl;}}
```